# How to access class names in a raster categorical map

Tags: r, raster

I have some classified raster layers as categorical land cover maps. All the layers having exactly the same categories (lets say: `"water", "Trees", "Urban","bare soil"`) but they are from different time points (e.g. 2005 and 2015)
I load them into memory using the raster function like this:

```
comp <- raster("C:/workingDirectory4R/rasterproject/2005marsh3.rst")
ref <-  raster("C:/workingDirectory4R/rasterproject/2013marsh3.rst")
```

`"comp"` is the `comparison map` at time `t+1` and `"ref"` is the `reference map` from time `t`. Then I used the `crosstab` function to generate the `confusion table`. This table can be used to explore the changes in categories through the time interval.

```
contingency.Matrix <- crosstab(comp, ref)
```

The result is in the `matrix` format with the `"comp"` categories in the `column` and `"ref"` in the `rows`. And `column` and `row` names labeled with numbers numbers `1 to 4`.

Now I have 2 questions and I really appreciate any help on how to solve them.

1- I want to assign the category names to the columns and rows of
    the `matrix` to facilitate it's interpretation.

2- Now let's say I have three `raster layers` for 2005, 2010 and 2015.
    This means I would have two `confusion tables` one for 2005-2010 and
    another one for 2010-2015. What's the best procedure to automate
    this process with the minimal interaction from user.

I thought to ask the user to load the raster layers, then the code save them in a list. Then I ask for a vector of years from the user but the problem is how can I make sure that the order of raster layers and the years are the same? And is there a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to my first question. If the categorical map is created in TerrSet(IDRISI) software with the ".rst" extention then I can extract the category names like this:

```
comp <- raster("C:/rasterproject/2005subset.rst")
attributes <- data.frame(comp@data@attributes)
categories <- as.character(attributes[,8])
```

and I get a vector with the name of categories. However if the raster layers are created with a different extension then the code won't work. For instance if the raster is created in ENVI then the third line of the code should get changed to:

```
categories <- as.character(attributes[,2])
```